# x86 memory ordering test shows reordering where Intel's manual says there shouldn't be?

Tags: c++, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers, lock-free

According to intel's manual.  Neither Loads Nor Stores Are Reordered with Like Operations
According to 8.2.3.2 Neither Loads Nor Stores Are Reordered with Like Operations

at document https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO2MC.png)

but I created a simple case, I found r1=1 and r2=2 happened.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

volatile int x;
int b[500];
volatile int y;
volatile int start;

int s1;
int s2;
int s3;
int s0;
int foo()
{
    while(start==0);
    x=1;
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
    y=1;
    return 0;
}

int fool2()
{
    int a,b;
    while(start==0);
    a=x;
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
    b=y;

   if(a==0 && b==1)
         s0++;
   if(a==0 && b==0)
         s1++;
   if(a==1 && b==0)
         s2++;
   if(a==1 && b==1)
        s3++;
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  while(1)
  {
     x=y=0;
     thread t1(foo);
     thread t2(fool2);
     start = 1;
     t1.join();
     t2.join();
     i++;
     if((i&0xFFFF)==0)
     {
           cout<<s0<<" "<<s1<<" "<<s2<<" "<<s3<<endl;
     }
  }
}
```

g++ -O2 -pthread e.cpp

gcc version 7.5.0

output:

69 86538 1 19246512

The four case (r1 and r2 with 0, 1 combination)  is all possible.

Comment: `volatile` is **not** a valid thread synchronization technique in C++.  That means your code has data races and those have undefined behavior, meaning your code does as well.

Comment: It's quite possible for the `b=y;` to execute on t2 before the `y=1;` executes on t1. A similar thing happens for the counts of `s1`.

Comment: Test code is testing intel process behavior. Intel memory order spec said the Neither Loads Nor Stores Are Reordered during core run program.

Comment: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO2MC.png

Comment: sorry, it my code error. b=y should be ahead of a=x.

Comment: I suggest checking generated asm first to ensure it does what you think it does. Your C++  code has undefined behaviour (basically compiler optimizations may produce completely different code than you expect). If you want to check your case -- either write in asm or make sure C++ compiler generated precisely what you want it to generate.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You're talking about ISO C++.  The question is using G++, i.e. GCC, which does support using `volatile` that way (notably in the Linux kernel's hand-rolled atomics with volatile and inline asm).  It's not *recommended*, but as I explained in [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) it does *work* in practice somewhat like `atomic` with `mo_relaxed` on compilers that handle it the way G++ does, on hardware with coherent caches (like all CPUs that current C++ implementations will start std::thread across.)

Comment: Looks like you don't set `start = 0;` *after* thread.join, so the next pair of threads will ignore their `while(start==0)` spin-loops.  I haven't yet figured out whether that could explain things, or if you have other bugs or wrong assumptions.  The `x=y=0` happens before the threads are even started, so that's safe; a newly-started thread won't see `1`s left over from the previous run.

Comment: Your code is broken: `foo.cpp:21:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void` in both `fool1` and `fool2`.  g++11.1 compiles those functions to infinite loops, I think (because it assumes the return path is unreachable because that would be UB), so nothing ever gets printed.  Also, g++ warns about the missing return type in your `main()` definition, but does accept it.

Comment: After fixing those bugs (including adding `start=x=y=0`), I did eventually get a few counts in the first column (and 2 in the 3rd) on my i7-6700k Skylake running Linux, so yeah there's something else weird about this code.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks. I find my code error. 
It should be at foo2 
    b=y;
   asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
   a=x;

Comment: Oh right, I see, you're reading the variables in the *same* order they were written, not opposite, so all possibilities can be a result of simple program-order interleaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at what Section 8.2.3.2 of the intel manual. In your example your are effectively doing:

| Processor 1 | Processor 2 |
| --- | --- |
| mov [ _x], 1 | mov r2, _x |
| mov [ _y], 1 | mov r1, _y |

Instead of what the intel manual says:

| Processor 1 | Processor 2 |
| --- | --- |
| mov [ _x], 1 | mov r1, _y |
| mov [ _y], 1 | mov r2, _x |

In the your example processor 2 may load _x before _x is set by processor 1 and then load _y after processor 1 stores it thus allowing for (r1=1, r2=0):

| Instruction | Processor |
| --- | --- |
| mov r2, _x | 2 |
| mov [ _x], 1 | 1 |
| mov [ _y], 1 | 1 |
| mov r1, _y | 2 |

In the Intel example processor 2 can only load _x after it loads _y and processor 1 only sets _y after it sets _x so (r1=1, r2=0) is impossible.

Here is some code that demonstrates the Intel behavior:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

volatile int x;
volatile int y;
volatile int start;

constexpr bool flipOrdering = true; //Set this to true to see Intel example, false to see your example
constexpr int jitter = 10000;       //Range of random delay inserted between load/stores to make differences more obvious

int s1;
int s2;
int s3;
int s0;
int foo() {

    while(start==0);

    for(volatile int i = rand()%jitter; i; --i);
    x = 1;
    
    for(volatile int i = rand()%jitter; i; --i);
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory");

    for(volatile int i = rand()%jitter; i; --i);
    y = 1;

    return 0;
}

int fool2() {
    int a, b;
    while(start==0);

    for(volatile int i = rand()%jitter; i; --i);
    if constexpr(flipOrdering) b = y;
    else a = x;

    for(volatile int i = rand()%jitter; i; --i);
    asm volatile("" ::: "memory");

    for(volatile int i = rand()%jitter; i; --i);
    if constexpr(flipOrdering) a = x;
    else b = y;

   if(a==0 && b==1)
         s0++;
   if(a==0 && b==0)
         s1++;
   if(a==1 && b==0)
         s2++;
   if(a==1 && b==1)
        s3++;

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int i=0;
    while(i< 1000) {
        x=y=0;
        thread t1(foo);
        thread t2(fool2);
        start = 1;
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        i++;

        if((i%100)==0) {
            cout<<s0<<" "<<s1<<" "<<s2<<" "<<s3<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's a [link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrWVX0AGTy1MAOWcARpjEIADsAJykAA6oQoTmtHaOLsoxcWZ0Xj7%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%2BpmjECBkjij6UsyeCxgW1jnjoACskYENGxAangGoALQoXgX6Hj%2BKbiLGq5Yact7YaKJAAQywFMoSYFvvmhZQdosFRsESGoehmFHrezBCCWgEUhAOgbto2irCAonrEJTiYJOxC0kJ7GLoRv6kbxFFUtR8xKhB6D0Yx8HMYe%2BKsRh7K3hWNH4deikprsBBTM2B7XqE77osezKnqw2jnpeHGplSzCugEJmpvewHPqyb4fvJLm3n%2BZHkqpoHgXRX4MXBCEsQZaHGQRJy3ngeZcqG/LUOKUoynKF4BLGtI5beRQeswsbEjlxGxSpeJqUlkEpbp6UGchmVsUFKZcTx5FPgJAkiWJAmSdJsnaFFHK5Up/7tSBVFddpPVpfpuiGYN2U%2BSm%2BWrIV0ZhiVeCStKwQVasjU0c1x0OqwHpVTRNWWSt%2BJUBAzARRpMjiQAbDoIOCoDCqcF%2BVm3im%2B4GEjtUnX9AMaR%2BoPg5DGNA7DP3w8iq56Mjx35f9UOcFj2gQ4FuMKp%2BxHw0Ign6CTKO/RT9NU%2BD2N0%2B%2BGkw0zqbbkj7PfbeNl2asDmLk5CmuYSvbeF5mhXsRakfsNd4Pk%2BA02HGiYXmrL23s1Co1Qz2u3ts9y1gQnDUMKS2Eymtt7PbnnuYt1si6yeG%2B27nCAgoqAqy7rsENoIdh7QUEc/DyEk%2BLCuu5zEBJ9B8aM/Tn7ecLhNoA4bKbN8iOl6XQniRuFc/PhNjfFNk21yzjeV8JzcN5sou1%2B4rCB5ezkE2rQ/EVLxD2d%2B8unFI4ysNI0HyK4sjyKg0gN8n%2B1CL6SILJw8gENIcijOMfYgPM8yAhf1837fIMqNI3BL0fq/SPIQggDIpCHyv4xwLASA0ABmAmQCgEAgFRBASAYAnBYF8EfAhD%2BEAAgv1IAEbwFRqTSH3qQIBkl6ASloKwLBK9SBYF7OodgqD8C7FMHgDEcJUG8kwMgYusw5DkDtPPUh/wAgFhknYLAqCVR4CcNg2efA6CMBYFQngkjBAiAkKgpQdRVDqBQGLQwvCP6QHGKgKIJQP5SBQhKeYqwUKsAMTsD278igsJKJYawvRaikHcEMdoIQ6hpHiHQZxqRYg%2BNoO43IHR%2Bh2LoXQJoPR7A1E6OEkoUSWjeDaCEzxRhWR%2BP6KyYJIwYYTCmDMMYD8pCL1IMvDha8pDiAABwgxQiDbgqxgDIGQHGYOVMIC4EICQcS8w6irDsMA9gAo94Xg3mzXQB8X4n1IAgD2HRzykDPhfK%2Bt81kX3vtwp%2BZTUGVPfp/b%2B0zSD/0QCASYBAojF3IJQCBUC6g1m6Wk/g0i2AcDkc84QYhJCkPrAWKI4i54L2fqQypEpi6XMJLmIktT6mNOaa02BgIOmDMgcM3pMMpm/1PufS%2B6z1nFO2eU1%2BUh9lfx/sfQFUhtDAoqW/Q5WLSAMOIHECw3AgA) to the the same code running in Compiler Explorer.